# Page container not centering with page justify center issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center my page container, while maintaining a left justify of content.

I originally was trying this with flexbox but was having issues, so it's somewhat mixed.

The main wrapper container is centered, however the container inside that isn't centering

Is this possible with flexbox? Why isn't the container centering even when I am telling it to justify center?

Link to pen: https://codepen.io/jacksonrose/pen/RwNbMMm

```
<div class="center">Logo</div>

<div class="pageWrapper">
  <div class="country">USA</div>
  <div class="stockistItems">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">Montana</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">California</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">Arizona</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.pageWrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
  .country {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .stockistItems {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    .item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 33%;
    }
  }
}
```

The main wrapper container is centered, however the container inside that isn't centering

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your wrapper clearly is centered. It's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: it appears to be at center only, could you please elaborate on exactly what issue you are facing.

Comment: @Paulie_D just added an image to clarify

Comment: @HimanshuSingh added an image to clarify

Comment: The main wrapper container is centered, however the container inside that isn't centering

Comment: In what way isn't it centred? Your content clearly does not extend to the end of the div.

Comment: What is this **supposed** to look like.

Comment: Equal spacing on each side of the inside div. There is extra white space on the right, and no white space on the left indicated in the picture

Comment: So like this: - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mdybxab

Comment: or this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RwNbyGW - It's still not clear which you want. The arrows don't really clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:33%`from `.item` and give `.stockListItems` a `justify-content: space-between`. This will stretch the `.item` divs out evenly to the end of the `.pageWrapper` container. Then give `.pageWrapper` a `width: 90%`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.pageWrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 90%;
}

.pageWrapper .country {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.pageWrapper .stockistItems {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pageWrapper .stockistItems .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*width: 33%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="center">Logo</div>

<div class="pageWrapper">
  <div class="country">USA</div>
  <div class="stockistItems">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">Montana</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">California</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="state">Arizona</div>
      <span>766 Brackbill Road Gap PA<br>17527-9457 <br>+1 800 309 1500</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to add a width to the wrapper since it already has a max-width?

Comment: @Paulie_D because when the wrapper is less than `800px` it takes up 100% of its parent container and `margin: 0 auto` becomes irrelevant.

Comment: So? That's irrelevant to the question and should be addressed in a media query.

Comment: @Paulie_D Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought they were trying to center the wrapper